# I can't write to a file in python when using the absolute path of the file

Tags: python, read-write

I have created a script to write to a file in python:

```
a_file = open("file:///C:/Users/xdo/OneDrive/Desktop/Javascript/read%20and%20write/testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt", "a+")
a_file.write("hello")
```

The absolute path of the file is: `file:///C:/Users/xdo/OneDrive/Desktop/Javascript/read%20and%20write/testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt`

However, the program does not write(append) to the file. I can run the program, but nothing happens to the file. The strange thing is that it works if I put the file in the same directory as the script and run the script using the location "testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt". That is:

```
a_file= open("testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt", "a+")

a_file.write("hello")
```

This works 100% and appends to the file. But when I use the absolute path of the file, it never works. What is wrong?

**Edit**
I tried everything and it still doesn't work

My code:

```
a_file= open("C://Users//xdo//OneDrive//Desktop//Javascript//read%20and%20write//testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt", "a+")

a_file.write("hello")
a_file.close()
```

This did not work. I also tried:

```
a_file= open("C:/Users/xdo/OneDrive/Desktop/Javascript/read%20and%20write/testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt", "a+")

a_file.write("hello")
a_file.close()
```

This did not work

**Edit (finally works)**

It finally works. I replaced the "%20" with a regular space " " and used the pathlib module like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
filename = Path("C:/Users/qqWha/OneDrive/Desktop/Javascript/read and write/testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt")
f = open(filename, 'a+')
f.write("Hello")
```

And now it writes to the file.
It also works using "with". Like this:

```
with open("c:/users/xdo/OneDrive/Desktop/Javascript/read and write/testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt", "a+") as file:
file.write("hello")
```

Comment: Try `C://Users//xdo//OneDrive//Desktop//Javascript//read%20and%20write//testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt"`

Comment: `file:///` is something which belongs to an URL, not to a path.

Comment: Don't forget to close the file after you have read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing "with". Also, replace the `%20` with a space. Python does not automatically decode this, but you shouldn't have an issue using spaces in the instance below.

```
with open("c:/users/xdo/OneDrive/Desktop/Javascript/read and write/testfile.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.write("hello")
```

In this case, if the file doesn't exist, it will create it. The only thing that would stop this is if there are permissions issues.

Comment: Yes it finally Worked!! I removed the %20 and replaced it with a space as such: open("c:/users/xdo/OneDrive/Desktop/Javascript/read and write/testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt", "a+"). And now it writes to the file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will work. when we open a file in python using the `open` function we have to use two forward slashes.

```
f = open('C://Users//xdo//OneDrive//Desktop//Javascript//read%20and%20write//testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt', 'a+')
f.write("writing some text")
f.close()
```

or you can use another way in which you have to use `from pathlib import Path` package.

```
from pathlib import Path
filename = Path("C:/Users/xdo/OneDrive/Desktop/Javascript/read%20and%20write/testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt")
f = open(filename, 'a+')
f.write("Hello")
f.close()
```

If still, your problem exists, then try another absolute path like `"C:/Users/xdo/OneDrive/Desktop/testfileTryToOVERWRITEME.txt"`